# Kotlin js globally handling for unhandled exceptions

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js

Is there a proper way in Kotlin-js to globally catch unhandled exception?

I have made a general attempt with window.onerror (see below).
The only reported error is on non_existing_function2, but nothing is reported for the other 2 cases.

Any guidance?
Thanks

```
window.onerror = { msg, url, line, col, error ->
   window.alert(“Error: $msg \nurl: $url\nline: $line\ncol: $col\nerror: $error”)
   true
}
async {
   throw Exception(“generated”)
}
async {
   js(“non_existing_function1();”)
}

js("non_existing_function2();")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`async`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/async.html) in *Kotlin* you're using is defined as

```
fun <T> async(block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T): Deferred<T>
```

Where [`Deferred`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/-deferred/) is stateful and doesn't propagate the exception anywhere. You could use `async { ... }.asPromise()` to bridge to *JavaScript* and propagate the rejection to handle it properly.